# Connected door space

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise asking for a topology on $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ such that every nontrivial proper subset of $X$ is either open or closed, but never both!

I was wondering for an arbitrary $X$ what can we say? 
and what are the solutions to the main problem?

Comment: the "main problem" being what?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma a topology on $X$ such that every nontrivial proper subset of $x$ is either open or closed, but never both!

Comment: I gave a few examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On any set $X$ we can pick a point $p$, and define two topologies :

The included point topology wrt $p$ on $X$ is the empty set plus all sets that contain $p$.

The excluded point topology wrt $p$ is $X$ plus all sets that do *not* contain $p$.

These always work as connected door spaces. These might be the only ones (for finite sets), I’m not yet sure. For infinite sets we can use a free ultrafilter on the set together with $\emptyset$, which is a connected door topology.